# Elasticsearch "span and"

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch query:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "minimum_should_match": 1,
        "should": {
            "span_not": {
                "exclude": {
                    "span_or": {
                        "clauses": [{
                            "span_near": {
                              ...
                            },
                            "span_near": {
                              ...
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }...
```

I need to have in include clause something like:

```
"span_or": {
clauses: [
{
    "span_near": {...}
}
,
{
    "span_and": {
        "clases": [
        {
            "span_near": {...}
        }
        ,
        {
            "span_near": {...}
        }
        ,
        ...
        ]
    }
}
]
```

}

I mean, that i have "or" query:

```
(span_near or span_near or span_near or ...)
```

And i want to get "and" query:

```
(span_near or (span_near and span_near) or ...)
```

How can i do it? There is no tag "span_and". What tag can i you instead?

**Update 1**

I have tried this:

```
"span_or": {
                            clauses: [
                            {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "путин.*"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ,
                            {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must": [
                                                {
                                                    "term" : { "message" : "test" }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "term" : { "message" : "rrr" }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ]
                        }
```

but i have a error:

> spanMultiTerm [match] must be of type multi term query

Comment: Have you tried with `bool` query and specify each `span_near` as clauses for the `must` section?

Comment: I have answered in Update 1

Answer (score 0):

Would normal `bool` queries solve your problem?

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                         {
                             "regexp":{
                                 "message": "путин.*"
                             }
                         },
                         {
                             "bool": {
                                 "must": [
                                     {
                                         "span_near": {...}
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "span_near": {...}
                                     }
                                 ]
                             }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work exactly like "span_not" and "include"/"exclude"?

Comment: Not exactly. `Span_not` is little more complex that simple boolean conditions. It takes into account if the include span and exclude span overlap in specific way. But maybe for your use case that does not matter. Here more info about `Span_not`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-not-query.html

Answer (score 0):

I using the following idea found [here](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/):

> In certain situations, it can be convenient to have a `SpanAndQuery`. You can easily simulate this using a `SpanNearQuery` with a distance of Integer.MAX_VALUE.

```
"span_or": {
    clauses: [
    {
        "span_multi": {
            "match": {
                "regexp": {
                    "message": "путин.*"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ,
    {
        "span_near": {
            "clauses": [
                {
                    "span_term" : { "message" : "test" }
                },
                {
                    "span_term" : { "message" : "rrr" }
                }
            ],
            "slop": 2147483647,
            "in_order": false
        }
    }
    ]
}
```